# Java: Mixing together two double bitstrings for Genetic Algorithm crossover

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, bitarray

I am implementing evolutionary neural network. I ran into problem when it comes to the crossover of two double values. I am evolving the weights of the links in the Neural Network.

```
    //Get the weights that I want to crossover
    double weightA = a.getWeight();
    double weightB = b.getWeight();
    //Round to 6 decimal numbers.
    weightA = (double)Math.round(weightA * 1000000) / 1000000;
    weightB = (double)Math.round(weightB * 1000000) / 1000000;
    //Convert the doubles to binary strings
    String binaryA = Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(weightA));
    String binaryB = Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(weightB));
    //Define random crossover point.
    int crossOverPoint = randInt(0, binaryA.length());
    //Put the strings together based on the crossover point.
    String newBinary = binaryA.substring(0,crossOverPoint) + binaryB.substring(crossOverPoint+1,binaryB.length());
    double newWeight = Double.longBitsToDouble(new BigInteger(newBinary, 2).longValue());
```

The problem I am encountering is that I am getting very large or very small weights after crossover which is probably the result of something about how many bits are used in each string for decimal places. How should I do this to get values after crossover that are similar to the two parents?

I had a workaround for this problem that gave me decent results but I am fairly sure that is not the correct approach, which basically finds the average between the two values and adds some Gaussian noise with standard deviation based on the interval of the original two values.

```
    double interval = Math.abs(weightA-weightB);
    double newWeight = (weightA+weightB)*0.5 + r.nextGaussian()*interval*2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with genetic algorithms, but from what I know your treatment of doubles doesn't seem to be a good way of approaching it:

I assume here that you want to use the first `crossOverPoint` bits of the binary representation of the first double and the last `(64-crossOverPoint)` bits of the second double (correct me if I'm wrong). If you use Strings you'll have to make sure to include leading 0s. The simpler approach would be to combine the binary representations of the longs using bit operations:

```
long weightALong = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(weightA);
long weightBLong = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(weightB);
long mask = -1L; // all bits set to 1
int crossOverPoint = randInt(0, Long.SIZE);
long combined;
// treat special cases because of modulo Long.SIZE of second parameter of shifting operations
if (crossOverPoint == 0) {
    combined = weightBLong;
} else if (combined == Long.SIZE) {
    combined = weightALong;
} else {
    combined = (weightALong & (mask << (Long.SIZE - crossOverPoint))) |
               (weightBLong & (mask >>> crossOverPoint));
}
double newWeight = Double.longBitsToDouble(combined);
```

However from the [binary representation of doubles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) I guess that combining the binary representations that way may not be the best way to combine doubles:

- If the first bits are different, the right choice of `crossOverPoint` (1) can just change the sign.
- the exponent comes completely from `weightA` in (52 / 64) of all cases.
- `NaN`, `POSITIVE_INFINITY`, and `NEGATIVE_INFINITY` can be produced from values different from all of these three if you get a unlucky combination in the mantissa.

I guess your workaround seems to be the better choice. (Maybe you should ask that question on https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This answer solves the problem of the newWeight not making any sense in terms of being way too small or way too big, at least in those cases I tested it with breakpoints. However I am not sure this makes the algorithm converge faster since the changes to the double are often very small after crossover. Only time will tell since convergence of the algorithm takes very long time for my application.

In some cases when weightA and weightB have different signs the new weight will for example have the sign from weightA while most of the precision from weightB.

Comment: I got quiet a nasty bug with the crossover resulting in NaN, so there definitely needs to be logic in place to prevent the crossover from doing that (simple while loop would be sufficient). Early tests show that this is not worse than my workaround and probably results in individuals in each generation evolving more naturally resulting in more diversity between individuals.